# Как получить значения в селект лист?

Tags: drupal, php

Есть один селект лист в котором показаны марки производителя, нужно сделать так что бы по выбору марки подтягивались модели в другой селект лист.  Помогите разобраться, не понимаю как это сделать. Вот мой код:

```
function filterform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $years = filterform_get_years();

    if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form'){

        $form['manufacturer'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'Марка',
            '#options' => filterform_get_terms(3),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'ajax_filterform_callback_func',
                'wrapper' => 'filter_fields'
            )
        );
        $form['model'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'Модель',
            '#options' => isset($_cats) ? $_cats : array('-Выберите модель-'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="filter_fields">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
    }

}
function filterform_ajax_callback(&$form, $form_state){
        $tid = $form_state['values']['manufacturer'];
        $td = db_query("SELECT * FROM taxonomy_term_data td WHERE td.`tid`='$tid'")->fetchObject();
        $vid = $td->vid;

        $categories = db_query("SELECT * FROM taxonomy_vocabulary tv
                               LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_data td
                               ON tv.`vid`=td.`vid`
                               LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy th
                               ON td.`tid`=th.`tid` 
                               WHERE td.`vid`='3'
                               AND th.`parent`='$tid'
                               ORDER BY td.`tid` ASC 
                              ")->fetchAll();
            foreach($categories as $key){
                $_cats[0] = '-Ничего не выбрано-';
                $_cats[$key->tid] = $key->name;
            }
        $form['model'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'Модель',
            '#options' => isset($_cats) ? $_cats : array('-Выберите модель-'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="filter_fields">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У друпала есть минимум три модуля, которые делают подобное:

1. https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select
2. https://www.drupal.org/project/shs
3. https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs

Я думаю, что могут вам подойти, в худшем случае, посмотрите, как там реализован процесс выбора.